# How does multiplication and power influence on domain and range?

Tags: algebra-precalculus

given $f(x) = x^2 + 4x + 2, f(x)\rightarrow [2, 3]$ 
$ran_{f} = [14, 23]$ 
let $g(x) = (f(x))^2 = (x^2 + 4x + 2)^2$ 
let $h(x) = 3 \cdot (f(x)) = 3 \cdot (x^2 + 4x + 2) $

given $m(x) = 2x, f(x) \rightarrow [0, 10]$ 
let $n(x) = f(x) \cdot m(x) = (x^2 + 4x + 2) \cdot (2x)$

what is the domain and range of $g(x)$, $h(x)$ and $n(x)$?

---

I am sorry if the question seems stupid, I am trying to build a Segment Common Algebraic Expression object, I have achieved multiplication and power by recursive function successfully, but I have two variables `xlim` and `ylim` I don't know what to do with it. I have forgotten all I learned in high school. I am truely sorry if you were my math teacher who is looking at this.

Comment: In the example it is easy, because the range of f is positive. Do you want a general answer or just this case?

Comment: Is $[2,3]$ the domain for $f(x) = x^2 = 4x +2$?

Comment: Yes please, I'd like a general solution for this, if you are using option cases that's ok.  I gave a random thought case in the example above.

Comment: For multiplication, the other may be integer, float and function.

Comment: For power, the other must be an integer

Comment: I answered the cases, if it is for use in programming, there is probably a simple way to unite the odd and even powers into one formula.

Comment: @Weilory I realised I made some mistakes in the answer. I will now make the edits.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd say it works like this.

For multiplication by $c$ we just get a range of $[ca, cb]$ for $af(x)$ if $f(x)$ has range $[a,b]$ and $c$ is positive. If $c$ is negative the range is $[cb, ca]$.

Powers are a little more complicated since for even powers the sign dissappears and negative powers are also a thing.
Suppose $f(x)$ has range $[a, b]$:
For odd powers we get the range of $f^c$ is $[min(a^c, b^c), max(a^c, b^c)]$.
For even powers we get the range of $f^c$ is $[min(|a|,|b|)^c, max(a^c,b^c)]$ if $c$ is even and either $a$ and $b$ are both odd or both even.
If they have opposite sign and even power, then we get as range $[0, max(a^c,b^c)]$.
We get this min max thing because the even power of a negative number is negative.